# Idiomatic way to handle nested IO in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell, and writing a short parsing script as an exercise. Most of my script consists of pure functions, but I have two, nested IO components:

1. Read a list of files from a path.
2. Read the contents of each file, which, in turn, will be the input for most of the rest of the program.

What I have works, but the nested IO and layers of fmap "feel" clunky, like I should either be avoiding nested IO (somehow), or more skillfully using do notation to avoid all the fmaps. I'm wondering if I'm over-complicating things, doing it wrong, etc. Here's some relevant code:

```
getPaths :: FilePath -> IO [String]
getPaths folder = do
    allFiles <- listDirectory folder
    let txtFiles = filter (isInfixOf ".txt") allFiles
        paths = map ((folder ++ "/") ++) txtFiles
    return paths

getConfig :: FilePath -> IO [String]
getConfig path = do
    config <- readFile path
    return $ lines config

main = do
    paths = getPaths "./configs"
    let flatConfigs = map getConfigs paths
        blockConfigs = map (fmap chunk) flatConfigs
    -- Parse and do stuff with config data.
    return
```

I end up dealing with `IO [IO String]` from using listDirectory as input for readFile. Not unmanageable, but if I use do notation to unwrap the `[IO String]` to send to some parser function, I still end up either using nested `fmap` or pollute my supposedly pure functions with IO awareness (fmap, etc). The latter seems worse, so I'm doing the former. Example:

```
type Block = [String]
getTrunkBlocks :: [Block] -> [Block]
getTrunkBlocks = filter (liftM2 (&&) isInterface isMatchingInt)
    where isMatchingInt line = isJust $ find predicate line
          predicate = isInfixOf "switchport mode trunk"

main = do
    paths <- getPaths "./configs"
    let flatConfigs = map getConfig paths
        blockConfigs = map (fmap chunk) flatConfigs
        trunks = fmap (fmap getTrunkBlocks) blockConfigs
    return $ "Trunk count: " ++ show (length trunks)
```

fmap, fmap, fmap... I feel like I've inadvertently made this more complicated than necessary, and can't imagine how convoluted this could get if I had deeper IO nesting.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi - welcome to stackoverflow and haskell! Congratulations I think you are on the best way to discover the usefulness of `(>>=)` and the concept of monads see [this blog post](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html)

Comment: also `sequence` or `traverse` = `mapM` might be useful

Comment: `join . fmap sequence :: IO [IO a] -> IO [a]` is pretty short. But it seems you just want, e.g. `mapM getConfigs`, to begin with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want something like this for your `main`:

```
main = do
    paths <- getPaths "./configs"
    flatConfigs <- traverse getConfig paths
    let blockConfigs = fmap chunk flatConfigs
    -- Parse and do stuff with config data.
    return ()
```

Compare

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

and

```
traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

They are quite similar, but `traverse` lets you use effects like `IO`.

Here are the types again specialized a little for comparison:

```
fmap     :: (a -> b)    -> [a] -> [b]
traverse :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]
```

(`traverse` is also known as `mapM`)

Comment: Thanks. Can't upvote you because I'm too new to SO, but that was what I needed. I'd read about mapM too, but didn't quite get my head around it. For anybody else that stumbles on this (need to reread it myself)...

[Monad tutorial in pictures](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html)

Answer (score 5):

Your idea of 'nestedness' is actually a pretty good insight into what monads are. Monads can be seen as Functors with two additional operations, return with type `a -> m a` and join with type `m (m a) -> m a`. We can then make functions of type `a -> m b` composable:

```
fmap :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m (m b)
f =<< v = join (fmap f v) :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

So we want to use join here but have `m [m a]` at the moment so our monad combinators won't help directly. Lets search for `m [m a] -> m (m [a])` using [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=m%20%5Bm%20a%5D%20-%3E%20m%20%28m%20%5Ba%5D%29) and our first result looks promising. It is `sequence:: [m a] -> m [a]`.
If we look at the related function we also find `traverse :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]` which is similarly `sequence (fmap f v)`.

Armed with that knowledge we can just write:

```
readConfigFiles path = traverse getConfig =<< getPaths path
```